# npm runs successfully but terminal process stopped (system limit)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, node-modules

I'm studying `Vue js` and when I try to run `npm run watch` it says that `Build successfully` but next for some reasons terminal process stops and I get an error like:

> Error from chokidar (/var/www/html/rankUp/node_modules/axios): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/var/www/html/rankUp/node_modules/axios'

In fact, it worked fine a few minute ago(I haven't any changes in code), but when I restart my PC and re run `npm run watch` I got that! By the way, I should say that noticed weird action by `axios` I was trying to handle api data with `axios`, next when I comment whole `axios` code, I saw that it still worked idk how? maybe that is a reason of that erros?

Does anyone have an idea? why it happend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are facing this error once you are trying to execute npm start, it’s because of your `max_user_watches` was reached the maximum number. Simply you can increase the `max_user_watches` by running this command :

```
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

And then you can run npm start again

Comment: Can you please explain more? why it happened and is it a really good idea and safe? to increase that `max_user_watches` ?

Comment: read here https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

Comment: It is just hitting your system's file watchers limit. don't worry. You may also read that https://flaviocopes.com/vue-watchers/#:~:text=A%20Vue%20watcher%20allows%20you,when%20that%20property%20value%20changes.

Comment: Thank you! I read, I run your code but it still returns same error. Are you sure that your code really works?

Comment: are you using windows?? any error while running that command?

Comment: No. I've Linux OS. and your code runs without any error. but I don't think that had any effect

Comment: play around those command https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

Comment: another way you can delete your node modules and reinstall after clearing cache

Comment: Yes I re install node modules and now it works. I think  your code worked. but get effect after re install modules. Thank you!

Comment: Sir today I checked again and have same error as yesterday, should I increase more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221041/discussion-between-king-neo-and-cike4ka).

Comment: Yes you can increase